# What English adjective means "separated from religious practices"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What adjective in English means, "divorced from religious doctrine"?

I think there is a suitable adjective beginning with the letter "s?"

It is not "sectarian."

An example usage would be in the sentence:

> "In the United States of America, public schools are [X]."

Answer (score 3):

I suggest two words

> Secular = not having any connection with religion:
>
> ”We live in an increasingly secular society, in which religion has less and less influence on our daily lives.”
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/secular)

> Temporal = relating to practical matters or physical things, rather than spiritual ones
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/temporal?q=Temporal)

Or

> Temporal = Relating to worldly as opposed to spiritual affairs; secular.
>
> ‘the Church did not imitate the secular rulers who thought only of temporal gain’
>
> [Oxford lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/temporal)

In the context of your question, *secular* seems preferable. The schools are secular, dealing only with temporal matters.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is "secular."

An example of the word "secular" being used in a sentence is shown below:

> Public schools in the United States of America are *secular*.

I will share my knowledge Q&A-style so that someone in the future, using a search engine asking a similar question, might find this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Could use Iconoclast.

with 's' may be sceptic.
But it is more like saying Public schools in the United States of America are religious disbelievers.

Comment: An iconoclast is a person who destroys religious images, often because of their own different religious beliefs - not relevant here at all.